# Partial derivative of a multivariable fraction

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need advice on how to approach finding $df/dx$ and $df/dy$. Am I on the right path?

Here is my question:
$$f(x,y) = (x^3y^2) / 1024$$

So my approach is to use the chain rule like this:
$$f'(x) = g(x) / h(x)$$

$$f'(x) = (3072x^2y^2 - 0) / 1024$$

$$f'(x) = 3x^2y^2$$

Comment: The chain rule isn't appropriate.  The quotient rule might be appropriate, but barely.  You don't even need the product rule.  Your answers do not appear to be correct, but I don't know what derivative you are attempting to take.

Comment: WARNING: Do not use $f'$ in multivariate calculus, it's not clear which partial derivative you're taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When solving $\frac{\partial {f}}{\partial {x}}$ treat $\frac{y^2}{1024}$ as a constant and differentiate $x^3$ as usual.

You will get
$$\frac{\partial {f}}{\partial {x}} = \frac{3x^2y^2}{1024}.$$
The partial derivative w.r.t. $y$ is similar but treating $x$ as a constant.